# Is wp_reset_postdata() redundant after the main loop?

Tags: loop

I'm confused about an example [from the docs:](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/#creating-secondary-queries-and-loops)

```
<?php
    // The main query.
    if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        the_title();                                                             
        the_content();                                                          
    endwhile;                                                                   
    else :                                                                      
        // When no posts are found, output this text.                           
        _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' );                         
    endif;                                                                       
    wp_reset_postdata();                                                        

    /*                                                                          
     * The secondary query. Note that you can use any category name here. In our example,
     * we use "example-category".                                               
     */                                                                        
    $secondary_query = new WP_Query( 'category_name=example-category' );        

    // The second loop. if ( $secondary_query->have_posts() ) 
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $secondary_query->have_posts() ) :
        $secondary_query->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    endwhile;
    echo '</ul>';
    endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Isn't the first `wp_reset_postdata()` completely redundant? Before querying `$post`, the secondary query overwrites it anyways right? Is there ever a case where it makes sense to call `wp_reset_postdata()` after the main loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first use of `wp_reset_postdata()` is not redundant its unnecessary.

Per the codex

> Use this function to restore the global $post variable of the main
>   query loop after a secondary query loop using new WP_Query. It
>   restores the $post variable to the current post in the main query.

So only use it after your secondary query to reset things back for your main query.

**NOTE:** a better location to put it would be within the if instead of after the else

```
if ( $arg ) :
    // loop
    wp_reset_postdata();
else :
    // no results
endif;
```

More infor on [wp_reset_postdata()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One small thing: AFAIK "redundant" and "unnecessary" can be used synonymously here. That is why - to me - your first sentence makes no sense.

Comment: @ben technically the first time you use something its not redundant, but it can be unnecessary